# Handling Cycle inside Runner; building could produce unreliable results after update xcode to xcode 15

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, ios17, xcode15

I am upgrading xcode into 15 and ios into 17 version. But when I try to build my flutter project in iphone 15 pro max, I get this error

```
Error (Xcode): Cycle inside Runner; building could produce unreliable results.
Cycle details:
→ Target 'Runner': CodeSign /Users/umsi06/Documents/project/devV17Ke18/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app
○ That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”
○ That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “Thin Binary”
○ Target 'Runner' has process command with output '/Users/umsi06/Documents/project/devV17Ke18/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Info.plist'
○ Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Users/umsi06/Documents/project/devV17Ke18/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex' to '/Users/umsi06/Documents/project/devV17Ke18/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex'
○ That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”
```

is there a way to solve this

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I managed to solve it by moving **Embed Foundation Extensions** right bellow **Copy Bundle Resources** in the Xcode Build Phases configuration like this
[image]

Note, that my project is quiet large and it is using things like OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex in the Embed Foundation Extensions phase. Thats why this was needed.

This might not work for everyone but might help someone with similar project config.

My other project config:

- cococapods v1.13.0
- Flutter 3.13.5

Comment: Hi I have done it, and finally I can build my project.. I run it from xcode to simulator and it is really fine, but when I try to do debugging from my code, it is really takes a long time to build. (Xcode build done and stuck in keep ```Launching...```) and another error show: here is my error log https://gist.github.com/wahyu-handayani/8815992e35b35f5e356cc981c99b917c can you give me a suggestion to solve this ?

Comment: This answer is worth 100 million upvotes! This cost me about a week of frustration to fix!.. I upgraded from Ventura to Sonoma which forced XCODE update to 15 and caused this. In the end i reinstalled back to Ventura which did not fix the issue (as the problem is probably with XCODE 15), reinstalled flutter and Android studio and then somehow found this which fixed the problem.. GOD BLESS YOU!

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I have to move up **Embed App Extensions** above **Copy Bundle Resources**

In sort **Embed Extensions** need to be up above **Copy Bundle Resources**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me aswell. The copy only when installing in the embeded foundation extension, solved the error but it didn't launch the widget. This Embed Foundation Extensions right bellow Copy Bundle Resources works. I hope moving Embed Foundation Extensions doesn't cause any other issues in the app.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone Feeling lost, this how to do it. I'm just providing a clarification for @MartinM answer.

In step 4: Make sure E**mbed App Extensions** is below **Copy Bundle Resources**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have watch extension within your project, you need to move it above **Copy Bundle Resources** as well, like this:

[image: img]